# Accessing database as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-authentication

I am doing a website after publishing the website it becomes NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account.
In my website I am accessing the database. Since my published network became NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, it can't access my sql server 2008 R2. How do I make it connect to my sql server?

I deployed the website using IIS7.

Comment: Please provide more details what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

"System" is local account, you can't give it access on other machine (assuming IIS and MSSQL are on different boxes).

The restriction you are hitting is that Windows permissions can't travel more than one box ("double-hop authentication" briefly discussed in [Double-hop authentication: Why NTLM fails](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx) ).

Easiest solution is to use SQL authentication, but it requires password information in connection string. Impersonating special account (or reverting to process acount that runs under particular account) is much more secure apporach.

Comment: I opened the iis7 and I clicked on the Application pools in the leftpane then many sites that am created appeared on the right pane..I rightclicked on the specified site.then clicked advance settings.. then a window is appeared in that window I changed the pool identity to Local system, and then the site had the permission to access the database.. My question is that is this is the required method

Comment: In my case MSSQL and IIS on same Machine

Comment: @user1751909, No, it is absolutely not required (and obviously discouraged) to run your website under system account to be able to access SQL database. Side note: you've fixed you shift key - cool, but for future questions try to provide details and ask question in a question instead of putting it in comments.